# how to set a string variable to some value in drool

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, drools

```
public class Policy{
    String accntCode;
    String currency;
    String flag;
}
```

and getter setters are generated for each of them.

Now I need to set the value of `flag` to `"Y"` if the `currency` is not `"INR"` and the `accntCode` starts with `"P"`. Kindly help me as I'm new to Drool.

and I have created an object policy of class `Policy` using

```
Policy policy = new Policy();
```

also please tell me if there is any way to debug in eclipse for Drool as we do for java code.

Comment: What have you coded so far? You need to write the rule, create a session, start it, insert facts and launch rule execution. All of this (and debugging in Eclipse) is described in the Drools manual, which should be read by novices.

Answer (score 0):

In Drools you need:

```
rule "Raise flag if currency isn't INR"
  when
    $p : Policy ( getCurrency() != "INR" )
  then
    $p.setFlag("Y")
```

And you'll need to create the appropriate getters and setters on the Java side.

Answer (score 0):

The following rules should work:

```
rule "Set flag \"Y\" when accntCode starts with 'P' and currency is not \"INR\""
    when
        a : Applicant(currency != "INR", accntCode str[startsWith] "P" )
    then
        a.setFlag("Y");
        System.out.println(a.getAccntCode() + "\t" + a.getCurrency() + "\t" + a.getFlag());
end

rule "Set flag \"N\" when accntCode doesn't start with 'P' and currency is not \"INR\""
    when
        a : Applicant(currency != "INR")
        not Applicant(accntCode str[startsWith] "P" )
    then
        a.setFlag("N");
        System.out.println(a.getAccntCode() + "\t" + a.getCurrency() + "\t" + a.getFlag());
end
```

So, when the fact is

```
app.setAccntCode("PHD");
app.setCurrency("EURO");
```

you'll get

```
PHD EURO    Y
```

When the fact is

```
app2.setAccntCode("HD");
app2.setCurrency("EURO");
```

you'll get

```
HD  EURO    N
```